# Why am I getting the "AttributeError" error

Tags: python

Good Evening All,
I have two classes that I'm working with
CardDeckService.py contains a method called GetCard which returns a string value:

```
import random
class CardDeckService:


      ShuffledCardDeck = None
      SelectedCards    = None
      MasterCardDeck   = None

      def __init__(self):
          self.ShuffledCardDeck = {}
          self.SelectedCards = {}
          self.MasterCardDeck = {}

      def BuildCardDeck(self):
          """
          BuildCardDeck() - builds a card deck of 52 cards 
          """
          cardDeck = {}
          cardTypes = "Clubs,Spades,Diamonds,Hearts".split(",")
          cardNumbers= "A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K".split(",")
          try:
              # Loop through the cardTypes array
                for cardType in cardTypes:

                    # Loop through the cardNumbers array
                    for cardNumber in cardNumbers:

                        # Create the key
                        key = "{} - {}".format(cardNumber,cardType)

                        value = ""
                        # Determine value
                        if cardNumber == "A":
                            value = "1or10"
                        elif cardNumber == "Q" or cardNumber == "K" or cardNumber == "J":
                            value = "10"
                        else:
                            value = cardNumber

                        # Add to consumer MasterCardDeck dictionary
                        self.MasterCardDeck[key] = value
          except:
              print("BuildCardDeck() - Error")


      def ShuffleCardDeck(self):
          """
          ShuffleCardDeck() - Shuffles the card deck in a random order and returns the shuffle card deck back to the consumer.
          """
          try:
              self.ShuffledCardDeck = {}

              # Copy the keys (Cards Display Name) to a local list
              Cards = list(self.MasterCardDeck.keys())

              # Shuffle the keys using random.shuffle
              rnd = random.shuffle(Cards)

              # Set the shuffle keys into the new dictionary
              for Card in Cards:
                  self.ShuffledCardDeck[Card] = self.GetCardValue(Card)
          except:
              print("ShuffleCardDeck() - Error")

      def GetCardValue(self, CardKey):
          """
          GetCardValue(CardKey) - Retrieves a card's numeric value
          param CardKey: represents tehe the Card face name.
          """
          # Get the master card deck
          CardValue =self.MasterCardDeck[CardKey]

          # Return the card value back to the consumer
          return CardValue





      def **GetCard**(self):
          PlayingCard = "A - Clubs" # list(self.ShuffledCardDeck.keys())[0]

          # Remove the card from the ShuffledCardDeck
          #del self.ShuffledCardDeck[PlayingCard]

          # return the card back to the consumer
          return "A - Clubs"
```

Dealer.py contains a method called DealStarterCards which class the CardDeckService.GetCard method to get a card

```
import User
import CardDeckService
class Dealer:
      UserBetsAmount = 0
      PlayingCards = []
      UserCards = []      
      Players = []
      CardDeckSvc = None

      Players = []
      def __int__(self):
          self.CardDeckSvc = CardDeckService.CardDeckService()
          self.CardDeckSvc.BuildCardDeck()
          self.CardDeckSvc.ShuffleCardDeck()

      # Deals initlal cards to users
      def DealStarterCards(self):

          playingCards = []

          svc = self.CardDeckSvc
          playingCards = []
          playingCards.append(svc.GetCard())
          playingCards.append(svc.GetCard())

          return playingCards
```

For some reason when I run the Dealer.py file using the following code:

```
dealer = Dealer()
print(dealer.DealStarterCards())
```

I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has not attribute 'GetCard'

I'm confused. Please help

Thank in you in advance

Comment: You forgot an 'i' in the `Dealer` class **init** method: `def __int__(self):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is too long for a comment, so I'm writing an answer).

You've misspelled `__init__` as `__int__`. Unfortunately, the story doesn't end  there.

You've also defined a class variable `CardDeckSvc` that's `None` initially. You're then attempting to define it inside the (misspelled) `__init__` constructor. However, the interpreter does not see a valid constructor at the time of object creation, so that method is never called and `CardDeckSvc` is never set.

So, when you end up calling `DealStarterCards`, `self.CardDeckSvc` is `None`, and `self.CardDeckSvc.GetCard()` throws an `AttributeError` exception.